# How does Django know which model manager to use?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

So I am interested in using the example code below in a Django project, but am puzzled when trying to understand how I would call one model manager explicitly.

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(AuthorManager,    self).get_queryset().filter(role='A')

class EditorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EditorManager, self).get_queryset().filter(role='E')

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))))
    people = models.Manager()
    authors = AuthorManager()
    editors = EditorManager()
```

I know the view calls the models and the models calls the model manager, but its kind of confusing to me. Can I specify which view calls which manager or does the model take care of that implicitly through some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/), you can call either model manager from your views with `Person.authors.get_queryset` or `Person.editor.get_queryset`. Additionally, you can pass data back to either manager. For example:

In views:

```
data = {
    'first_name' : request.POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' :request.POST['last_name'],
    'email' : request.POST['email'],
  }
author = Person.authors.new_author(data)
editor = Person.editor.new_editor(data)
```

The "author"/"editor" variable above will become whatever your models passes back.

Obviously, you would want to define new methods in your managers. E.g.

In models:

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def new_author(self):
        Person.authors.create(...)

class EditorManager(models.Manager):
    def new_editor(self):
        Person.editors.create(...)
```

You can choose to have your models pass back whatever user info you need to your views.

Comment: So in my PersonViewSet can I call Person.authors.filter(name='eric') or something along those lines? That is the main disconnect I am having with how to truly utilize this.

Comment: Yea, totally, you can make a simple db call in the views, but for more complicated logic like validations, etc. you want to push that back to the models.

Comment: And any work that you can push back to the models, have a Manger handle, e.g. create a user with validations. Best to distribute as much of the logic to the models (and out of the views) as possible.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of how I would push that logic back to the models and then call them from the views? I thought the views sole purpose was to take a request and serve a response. But that involves the view doing the logic. I'd like to see your way be implemented.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you want to have skinny controller, fat models. Thus, if you have a form on your site and want to make sure that every field has a value (a certain amount of characters, or email regex) before it is submitted to your database, you will need to do validations. This can take up many lines of code, so you put the validations in your model manager, then, for example, have manager to send error messages back to your view if the validations haven't been met. Is that clear?

Comment: that makes sense. can you show me how this would be implemented?

Answer (score -1):

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def authors(self):
        return self.filter(role='A')

    def editors(self):
        return self.filter(role='E')

class Person(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))))
        people = models.Manager()
        objects = PersonQuerySet.as_manager()
```

**Get authors and editors:**

```
authors = Person.objects.authors()
editors = Person.objects.editors()
```